# Do not understand where 2048 comes from

Tags: filesystems, operating-system

Where does the `2048` number comes from in is the problem?

Consider a file system that uses inodes to represent files. Disk blocks are `8 KB` in size and a pointer to a disk block requires `4 bytes`. This file system has `12 direct disk blocks`, as well as single, double, and triple indirect disk blocks. What is the maximum size of a file that can be stored in this file system?

```
(12 * 8 KB) + (2048 * 8 KB) + (2048 * 2048 * 8 KB) + (2048 * 2048 * 2048 * 8 KB) = 64 terabytes
```

I was thinking 8KB/4B, but isn't that 2000?  8000/4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes when discussing numbers in the context of computers, `kB` = 1024 bytes, `MB` = 1,048,576 bytes, etc.

In this case, `8kB` = 8192 bytes. 8192 / 4 = 2048.

Answer (score 8):

`2048` is 8K (the block size) divided by `4` (the size of a pointer).

You need to allocate an entire `8192`-byte block of pointers to 8K blocks; you can fit `2048` pointers into one of these.

Further, you can fit `2048` pointers to blocks of pointers to block for additional `2048 * 2048 * 8 KB` capacity, and then `2048 * 2048 * 2048 * 8 KB` of pointers to blocks of pointers to blocks of pointers to 8K blocks.

If you think that it goes a little like a [cumulative tale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_the_House_That_Jack_Built), you're not alone.